# FTP client with cyberduck like 'open in your editor' functionality

Tags: ftp, sftp

On mac os there is a great ftp client called cyberduck that upon connection offers you to open any file on the server with you preferred text editor. Which essentially downloads the file in a temporary folder, opens it in your text editor and upon saving uploads it back to the server. I know there are plenty of ftp clients for linux, but I yet to come across one that provides this feature. Can someone mention one to me?

Thanks

Comment: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ Is specifically for software recommendations as you appear to have a firm grasp on what exactly you are looking for I believe your question would be on topic there.

Comment: Really, you can just use the file manager to do this. Connect to an ftp:// URL in Nautilus, and you can just open a file normally and it will open in your text editor, or you can right-click on files to get the "open with" menu for more options.

Comment: @dobey do you mind posting your comment as an answer so I could close the question?

Comment: Software recommendations are off topic, so no, I'd prefer not to post it as an answer, as this question should be closed as off topic/too broad/opinion based, anyway.

Comment: @dobey software recommendations are not off topic ([1](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/15638/85695), [2](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/14394/85695) and many more). I often wish they were, but that's not the case. As such, please do post your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All text editors with GVFS (e. g. Gedit, Gnome's default text editor) or KIO (e. g. Kate, KDE's default text editor) support can open files on "virtual" file systems including FTP network resources.

In addition you'll need a file manager than knows about GVFS/KIO so it can browse virtual directories and knows how to tell GVFS/KIO-enabled applications to open resources on such file systems. Examples for such file browsers are

- Nautilus, Ubuntu's/Gnome's default file manager,
- Thunar, Xubuntu's/Xfce's default file manager,
- Nemo, a fork of Nautilus,
- Dolphin, Kubuntu's/KDE's default file manager,
- Konqueror (also KDE).

You can instruct those file manager to access FTP directories [as outlined in this answers about SFTP](/a/349879/175814) – just replace all instances of `sftp` with `ftp`.

This works for all file types for which you have GFVS/KIO-enabled viewers/editors. Examples are Eye of Gnome, Totem, and Evince, Ubuntu's/Gnome's default image viewer, multimedia viewer and PDF viewer, respectively.

A nice thing about this approach is that the application doesn't need to transfer the whole file before it can be viewed if a partial view is possible (and implemented), e. g. for long video files. Even seeking within a file is possible like this.

---

P.S.: I just tested this with Nemo and noticed the following detail: if a text file doesn't have a file name extension that hints to its textual content (e. g. `.txt` or `.log`) file browsers normally try to guess its content type based on the actual content. However that is infeasible for remote files. Hence you'll need to tell your text editor explicitly to open that file, e. g. by dragging it from the file browser onto the text editor window.

Comment: It doesn't matter if your local editor supports opening remote files or not. if you use Nautilus/Firefox/Chrom{e,ium} and many others. At least for Nautilus, if the local editor doesn't support remote files (as described in it's .desktop file) then Nautilus will save the file to a local temporary path and open it in the editor.

Comment: @dobey: Nice – I didn't know that. Feel free to add that to the answer.